# Persistent time out issues copying very large tables across SQL Server 2012 instances on Amazon RDS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, smo, sqlbulkcopy

To give some context, I'm currently running a SQL Server 2012 instance on Amazon RDS and I've had to move to a larger instance twice already. The first time SQLAzureMW was the way to go, but at the time no table was that significantly large. The second time, SQLAzureMW always timed out the source server on the bcp command with large tables (a few over 5 GB). Similarly, SSIS Import / Export Wizard also timed out. I found the source server was always the problem so I tried increasing the instance's class from an m1.medium to an m1.xlarge to no avail, the source server still always timed out before making any significant progress on the large tables.

In the end I ended up writing my own .NET program that simply ran a "SELECT * FROM [table] ORDER BY [id] OFFSET {0} ROWS" on the large source tables and pushed the results into SQLBulkCopy on the destination server. Again the source server timed out repeatedly but I wrapped the try and catch statements in a loop that would simply resume the query from the last point where SQLBulkCopy. That being said, I'm not exactly thrilled with this solution.

I'm considering building a solution around the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer class but I'm afraid there might be the same problems with lack of recovery from a broken source connection.

I'd much rather an out of the box solution for this like SQLAzureMW was before tables got too large and that I'd expect SSIS Import Export Wizard to be. There has to be a better way.

Comment: I wonder if this is better asked on Programmgers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I'd rather not further develop an application as anything other than a last resort. I'd much rather solve the time out issues or find an out of the box solution like SQLAzureMW was until the tables got too large.

Comment: Can you increase the timeouts? What component exactly is timing out? bcp has no timeout as far as I'm aware.

Comment: SQLAzureMW runs bcp for each of the tables. It's at this point it stalls.

SQLState = 08S01, NativeError = 10060
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
SQLState = 08S01, NativeError = 10060
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Communication link failure
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Protocol error in TDS stream

Comment: This error is a TCP level error (it says that). Is the connectivity alright? It can't be.

Comment: The SQL Servers are Amazon RDS instances and SQLAzureMW is running on an Amazon EC2 instance all in the same VPC on the same subnet. That said, I don't experience connectivity problems otherwise.

Comment: The solution turned out to be use a c3 compute optimized instance such as c3.large or c3.xlarge to be safe. I'm not exactly sure why but while all the other instances inevitably choke. Perhaps it's a different virtual network device or the other instances virtual CPU is somehow throttled or maybe surprisingly the SQL Server Import Export Wizard continuously sustains 20 MB/s write to the temp folder or maybe a bit of each this. Regardless, these instance classes solve my problems. Thank goodness because I wasn't keen on writing an application.

Answer (score 5):

We were running into a similar situation: running SQLAZureMW on an Window server 2012 EC2 instance connecting to SQL Server 2012 RDS Instance. AWS support suggested the following changes on our EC2 instance and it seems to have solved all of our issues:

1. Increase TCP/IP timeout value as described here (i'm not sure this is actually necessary) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html
2. Disabling all TCP offloading for the network adapter.

Instructions from AWS:

> Here are the steps to disable TCP Offloading: Go to the properties of
>   the Citrix PV ethernet adapter Click Configure Go to Advanced Disable
>   all of the following Properties: 
>   IPv4Checksum Offload Large Receive Offload (IPv4),  Large Send Offload
>   Version 2(IPv4),  TCP Checksum Offload (IPv4), UDP Checksum Offload
>   (IPv4)
>
> Then as a final step run the following command from the command
>   prompt:
>
> ```
> netsh int ip set global taskoffload=disabled 
> netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled 
> netsh int tcp set global rss=disabled 
> netsh int tcp set global netdma=disabled
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been known and reported to MSFT. The problem here is not with SQL Server (your source). The NIC drivers for the network card have a feature called TCP chimney which offloads the bulk data movement from the CPU to the network card. i.e For large data movement, the CPU does not get involved and rather relies on the network card to process the data. But while doing so, the NIC card some times runs out of memory (known bug).

You can simply turn off the Chimney feature off and give it another try. If your source is a production box, you may want to create a backup of the DB before doing anything with that machine (just to be on the safe side). People have reported resolving this problem by turning the feature off. Here is a [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945977) you can follow.

Comment: I am not too sure how you would go about this on RDS, but you may want to get support from Amazon as well for this. They should have a resolution.

Comment: On RDS TCP Chimney can be disabled through Powershell but it was already disabled.
"netsh int tcp show chimneystats"
"Your System Administrator has disabled TCP Chimney."

Comment: If TCPChimney is off, I am afraid there are not many known work arounds. Can you break your data set into more managagle chunks (maybe by days or weeks) and then process the batch in a loop untill you reach your target?

Comment: It looks like I'll have to industrialize the approach that I've been working with, using SqlBulkCopy on the destination database against a SELECT query with an OFFSET statement on the source database wrapped in a try catch inside a while loop. Each time SqlBulkCopy throws an exception, it just picks up from the last known number of rows copied.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I answered this but it turns out the problem was the instances I chose. I believe the m1 class of instances shared the same hardware network device for SAN storage and networking. The result being that enough network activity caused the system drive, and thus the virtual memory, to become inaccessible at least for an instant. Spending the money on newer hardware, m2 and above, solved the problem.